# Does the assumption $0^0=1$ ever lead to a contradiction or conflict with another useful assumption?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, polynomials, definition, convention

There are some places where the assumption $0^0=1$ is formally useful.  For example when expressing polynomials

$$f\left[x\right]=\sum_{i=0}^{n}a_i x^i.$$

That leads me to question whether $0^0=1$ can be assumed in all cases.

**Does the assumption $0^0=1$ ever lead to a contradiction or conflict with another useful assumption?**

Comment: The only place that I think it might lead to some problems is that if you take the natural log of both sides. You will get: $0ln(0)=ln(1)$. Then:$ ln(0)=ln(1)/0$. Which means that we are setting a value for when we divide by zero.

Comment: That is certainly a special circumstance in need of exclusion.  If there were too many such exceptions, the assumption would not be useful as a convention.  But unless that special case breaks something else, it seems to be a tolerable exception.

Comment: It interferes with the arguably useful assumption that $(x, y) \mapsto x^y$ is continuous on its domain.

Comment: For all $x > 0$, the convention is that $0^x = 0$. So it conflicts with that convention.

Comment: @JoelCohen: Doesn't that follow from continuity rather than a convention?

Comment: @JoelCohen: This is too useful to be a contradiction! $0^x$ is used many times in combinatorial enumeration to filter the addends of a sum that have $x = 0$. For example, the alternating sum of the entries in the $n$-th row of Pascal's triangle is $\left(1-1\right)^n = 0^n$, which is $1$ if $n=0$ and $0$ otherwise. You don't want to change Pascal's triangle, so you shouldn't want to change $0^n$.

Comment: @Clayton : that's exactly the point : extending a definition using continuity **is** a convention. If $x > 0$, we can say that $ \lim_{y \to 0} y^x = 0$, so it would seem reasonable to say that $0^x = 0$. But then $\lim_{x \to 0} 0^x = 0$, so extension by continuity in that way leads us to $0^0 = 0$. In a nutshell, the problem is that $y^x$ has different limits at $(0,0)$ depending on how $x$ and $y$ go to $0$.

Comment: But then your comment is essentially just restating Theo Bendit's comment. That is why I asked (and for what it's worth, this is why $(0,0)$ is not in the domain for $x^y$ :) ).

Comment: @darijgrinberg : I agree this convention is very useful. I'm not suggesting we change it. Just pointing out that conventions have a limited scope, and sometimes they may conflict we each other at the fringe.

Comment: @Clayton : yes, my comment points to the same mathematical phenomenon. My aim wasn't to restate Theo's comment, we just typed it independently.

Comment: @Steven Hatton . https://fr.scribd.com/doc/14709220/Zero-puissance-zero-Zero-to-the-Zero-th-Power

Comment: @darijgrinberg What happens to the obvious result $0\times0=0=0^2$?  I will argue that in a combinitorial situation we are "patching" the function.  But the same could be said of my original example.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is what exactly you're looking for, but I think if nothing else it's notable.

Well, if we assume $0^0=1$, then in limits we should be able to use that whenever we evaluate by substitution (assuming continuity). As it happens, taking this idea from a pair of videos by blackpenredpen,

$$\lim_{x\to 0^+} x^x = 1 \;\;\;\;\; \text{but} \;\;\;\;\; \lim_{x\to 0^+} x^{\frac{1}{\ln(3x)}} = e$$

(Videos for the [first limit](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hjEwb-zfJFM) and [second limit](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zyQtN7Zbi-c) are linked.)

The core idea for the first limit: we do some manipulations and utilize the continuity of the function on the positive reals, and then use L'Hopital's rule:

$$\begin{align}
\lim_{x\to 0^+} x^x &= \lim_{x\to 0^+} e^{x \ln(x)} \\
&= \exp \left(\lim_{x\to 0^+} x \ln(x) \right)\\
&= \exp \left(\lim_{x\to 0^+} \frac{\ln(x)}{1/x} \right)\\
&= \exp \left(\lim_{x\to 0^+} \frac{1/x}{-1/x^2} \right)\\
&= \exp \left(\lim_{x\to 0^+} -x \right) \\
&= \exp(0) \\
&=1
\end{align}$$

For the second limit, similar manipulations yield

$$\begin{align}
\lim_{x\to 0^+} x^{\frac{1}{\ln(3x)}} &= \exp \left( \lim_{x\to 0^+} \frac{\ln(x)}{\ln(3x)} \right)\\
&= \exp \left( \lim_{x\to 0^+} \frac{1/x}{1/(3x) \cdot 3} \right)\\
&= \exp \left( \lim_{x\to 0^+} 1 \right)\\
&= e
\end{align}$$

Notice however that naive substitution at the start for both yield a $0^0$ case. (In the second limit, $1/\ln(3x) \xrightarrow{x \to 0^+} 0$.)

Comment: "then in limits we should be able to use that whenever we evaluate by substitution": Only if we assume continuity for no obvious reason.

Comment: That appears to be a problem whether or not we make the general assumption $0^0=1$.  Obviously, at least one of the two proofs cannot be logically dependent upon the naively assumed value of $0^0.$  But this is certainly the kind of objection I want to consider.